# MySQL not working after Windows 8.1 update

Tags: mysql

I don't know what happened to my MySQL. I already tried unstalling and reinstalling the MySQL Workbench 6.0.7 multiple times but it's still not working.. The server status is "Stopped"

Here's the message after trying to start the server

```
2014-12-09 23:08:23 - Workbench will use cmd shell commands to start/stop this instance
2014-12-09 23:08:26 - Starting server...
2014-12-09 23:08:30 - Server start done.
2014-12-09 23:08:31 - Checking server status...
2014-12-09 23:08:31 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2014-12-09 23:08:31 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)
2014-12-09 23:08:31 - Assuming server is not running
2014-12-09 23:08:31 - Checking server status...
2014-12-09 23:08:31 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2014-12-09 23:08:31 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)
2014-12-09 23:08:31 - Assuming server is not running
```

My touch pad also won't scroll after the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you just get the [Windows Installer for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/) and let it install the server for you. That is a super easy task, no messing with the command line or manual service registration.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the question found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525736/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-10061-2003). According to one of the answers, I would try this out:

```
Install the server as a service using this command: C:> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --install
```

Comment: Sorry but I am really clueless on installing MySQL. Where will I exactly install the server as a service? I don't have the MySQL Server 5.5 folder

Comment: Ok well from what I looked at with this answer, you need to type that in your COmmand Prompt

Comment: I need to type this whole thing right? C:> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --install. It says the system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: @nubteens type this in: `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --install`

Comment: It still says the system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Ok can you go to your windows explorer and look for MySQL Server, chances are you may need to change the version number...