# MySQL ERRO: Not connected while trying to connect via command line

Tags: mysql

Whenever I try to type anything into the MySQL shell I get the following message: `ERROR: Not connected.` Could some body please tell me what to do? I am using a 64-bit Windows 7 version.

I tried to run `C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --console` and it says `Shutdown complete` every time I run it.

I tried to run `C:\>....mysql` I got the following message : `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`

I tried `mysqld --install` I got `Install/Remove of the Service Denied!`

Comment: Please provide more information. Where's your server running, how do you start the `mysql` command, what else have you tried?

Comment: The server is running on localhost, port 3306

Comment: please mention your command line to connect to mysql . and also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525736/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-10061-2003

Comment: Hi. I forgot to mention a little detail which I added to the question description in the last paragraph. Please excuse me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I forgot that I needed to run

```
mysql --host=localhost --port=3310 --user=root -p
```

Thanks anyway for all those that tried to help me.