# MySql Workbench, Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

***This might seem like a duplicate but trust me its not***

So you guys are probably familiar with the error. The server doesnt start at the beginning and when i try to start it from Startup/Shutdown it gives this error.

Most of the people with this problem fixed it by starting MySQL server manually. Yeah but problem is mine was already working, i mean the server is on both in services and task manager. But for some reason im getting this error.

So my question is, how can i fix this?

```
 - Checking server status...
 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)
 - Assuming server is not running
```

Tried finding some logs but all says the same as above

Oh and i tried shutting the server down and opening again

***Do you guys think that it might be happening because it is conflicting with some other sql program? I uninstalled everything related to sql but i might miss some stuff.***

Programs i used to have are

```
 -XAMP
 -SQL Manager
 -Microsoft SQL Server
 -Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
```

***Like I said though, i uninstalled them all.***

Comment: Are you sure none of the answers of this question serves your purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525736/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-10061-2003

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061) (2003)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525736/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-10061-2003)

Comment: Yes, i tried that first. If you read my question, i said i did try those and server is online. Regardless, it does not connect to server

Comment: Remove C:\ProgramData\MySQL folder and reinstall mysql server again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like for some reason it was having a conflict with other connection or port was just wrong on set up. I tried deleting all the connections i have and started a fresh one and it worked. Weird right? Here i was thinking when you uninstall MySQL, it woudl delete all the connections too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for all the `mysql` configuration files in `/etc/mysql` and check for any lines containing `127.0.0.1` and bound address or skip network and comment them.

Hope it helps.