# Starting MySQL as a service in windows twice

Tags: mysql

I followed this answer not realizing that MySQL is already started in my computer. will that affect anything and how can I delete it?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24548331/14105177

> Looks like the MySQL server is not started.
> Look to the official documentation of MySQL how you can start a service under windows.
>
> > Install the server as a service using this command: C:> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --install

Comment: now I have two mysqls in services

Answer (score -1):

Decide which one you want to delete, then find its internal service name in the properties (it's the first thing shown at the top of the properties window), then execute `sc delete xxxxx` (as admin) with its internal name to delete it. (If it's running, stop it first before you delete it.)

See this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-windows-service-in-vista-or-xp/